# How can I allocate a matrix with structs?

Tags: c, struct

I must write a function that should help me to allocate a matrix using a struct. I Began to study the structs today.
So I wrote this  code with that struct and relative main to prove the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {

  int rows; 
  int cols;
  float **row_ptrs;
} Mat; 

Mat* Mat_alloc(int rows, int cols);

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
      Mat *m1 = Mat_alloc(int rows, int cols);

     return 0;
}
Mat* Mat_alloc(int rows, int cols)
{
    Mat matrice;
    matrice.rows = rows;
    matrice.cols = cols;
    float** matrice= (float**)malloc((matrice.rows)*sizeof(float*));
    for(int i = 0; i < matrice.cols; i++)
    {
        matrice[i] = (float*)malloc((matrice.cols)*sizeof(float));
    }
    matrice.row_ptrs = matrice;
    return matrice;
}
```

I know that I make some mistakes.Someone can help me to undestand how  I can do it ?

Comment: First find a [good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn how to call functions. Then continue reading the books and learn about *scopes* and what happens with local variables once the function they were defined in returns.

Comment: Note: Code will eventually need with a companion `Mat_free(Mat *);`

Comment: There is no matrix (aka 2D array) in your code and nothing which can be used as one. A pointer is not an array and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrisd1100 gave a good answer, but only to be a little bit pedantic this is mine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {

  int rows;
  int cols;
  float **row_ptrs;
} Mat;

Mat* Mat_alloc(int rows, int cols);

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    int rows = 10;
    int cols = 10;

    Mat *m1 = Mat_alloc(rows, cols);

    for (i=0; i<cols; i++)
    {
        free(m1->row_ptrs[i]);
    }
    free(m1->row_ptrs);
    free(m1);

    return 0;
}

Mat* Mat_alloc(int rows, int cols)
{
    Mat *m1 = malloc(sizeof(Mat));
    m1->rows = rows;
    m1->cols = cols;
    m1->row_ptrs = malloc((m1->rows)*sizeof(float*));
    for(int i = 0; i < m1->rows; i++)
    {
        m1->row_ptrs[i] = malloc((m1->cols)*sizeof(float));
    }

    return m1;
}
```

Comment: let me see if I really known how to deallocate it. I had to do, first two deallocations with that I can deallocate the matrix defined in the structs Mat (float **row_ptrs), but then I had also to  deallocate m1 that is of type Mat. Isn' it?

Comment: Yes, it is. You free them in the reverse order you allocate them.

Comment: Thank you for your support :)

Comment: Ri-prego. Di nulla

Answer (score 2):

`int rows` and `int cols` are uninitialized going into `Mat_alloc`. You need to give those numerical values!

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
      int rows = 10;
      int cols = 10;
      Mat *m1 = Mat_alloc(rows, cols);

      //do something
      //call your Mat_free(m1) function

     return 0;
}
```

Make sure you return the pointer to a `Mat` structure in this function too:

```
Mat* Mat_alloc(int rows, int cols)
{
    Mat *m1 = malloc(sizeof(Mat));
    m1->rows = rows;
    m1->cols = cols;
    float** matrice= (float**)malloc((m1->rows)*sizeof(float*));
    for(int i = 0; i < m1->rows; i++)
    {
        matrice[i] = (float*)malloc((m1->cols)*sizeof(float));
    }
    m1->row_ptrs = matrice;
    return m1;
}
```

Also, make sure you create a `Mat_free` function to `free` up the memory allocated in `Mat_alloc`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Curious: why the unnecessary cast `(float*)` in `matrice[i] = (float*)malloc((m1->cols)*sizeof(float));`?

Comment: @chux naughty question ;)

Comment: I use this because the function malloc is a void* function.

Comment: @LPs  Yes and no.  I _am_ interested in why folks use certain coding paradigms that have debatable value.

Comment: @MicheleColuccelli but you are coding using [tag:c] where it is allowed to assign a `void *` to another type, rather then [tag:c++] where is not allowed.

Comment: @MicheleColuccelli Take a look at [this fmaous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @MicheleColuccelli Another thing that is not necessary is to use a temp variable (`matrice`) to create the matrix. You could use `m1->row_ptrs` directly.

Comment: @LPs Thank you for this!

Comment: @MicheleColuccelli Prego ;)

Comment: @chux  I try to leave the code as similar to the OP's code as possible, but in working order. I don't want to reinterpret his motives for casting / using tmp variables.

Comment: Agree, Not fixing working legacy code is a reason to leave the cast.